# VScode Icon Window is not updated immediately

Tags: visual-studio-code

[Icon Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw7Uq.png). 
 I'm using vscode as a development tool now, but it doesn't appear right away in the icon window when I'm using "python -m Venv myvenv" or when I write commands to create a new folder, such as "django-admin startproject hello." How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I knew there was a refresh button in the icon window!